# Different speed on Internet connection by switching NICs. Can someone make sense of this?

Tags: networking, ethernet

I solved my Internet speed problem, but I'm still puzzled. I can't understand what happened.

My scenario: a small intranet is connected to Internet through a Linux gateway that connects to a Cable Modem (Motorola SBV5121), my provider gives me static IP and the nominal speed is 3Mbps/512Kbps.

The Linux gateway is an old Centos 5.10, with iptables and Dhcp server, with two NICs:

```
eth0 (Intranet) # 3Com Corporation 3c905C-TX/TX-M [Tornado]
eth1 (Internet) # Sundance Technology Inc / IC Plus Corp IC Plus IP100A Integrated 10/100 Ethernet MAC + PHY


[INTERNET]---[Motorola CableModem]----[eth1 LINUX-GW eth0]-----[LAN]---[desktop machines]
```

All pretty standard, and it was working for a long time; but lately I was experiencing low speed, especially when downloading. The usual tests (eg http://www.speakeasy.net/speedtest/ ) reported (consistenly) very low speeds (about 200Kpbs) when downloading from USA (I'm in South America); the speed was decent (though never reaching my 3Mbps limit) when downloading from my country: 1Mbps to 1.5 Mbps . The upload speed was right, near the 512Kbps limit. I had no problems with pings, no lost packets, both NIC reported a 100Mbps full-duplex connection. The tests were done from a desktop Windows machine, inside the LAN, but the behaviour was consistent with what I got when downloading from inside the Linux GW. Disabling iptables gave no difference.

I was pretty sure that it was a routing or shaping problem on my provider. On calling, they asked me to test the speed connecting a plain single Windows computer to the Cable Modem. I was extremely skeptical that it would make a difference.

```
[INTERNET]---[Motorola CableModem]----[Windows desktop machine]
```

To my astonishment it certainly did: the speed was right (3Mbps/512Kbps, whatever target).

I was very puzzled, I double checked everything, didn't find anything. The traceroute were the same. As a last resort, I tried switching the NICs in the GW. I didn't change the cables, nor the configuration, I did the simplest thing: I changed the MAC in the "ifcfg-ethX" configuration files, so that eth1 keeps connected to Internet, but the NICs are switched:

```
eth0 (Intranet) # Sundance Technology Inc / IC Plus Corp IC Plus IP100A Integrated 10/100 Ethernet MAC + PHY
eth1 (Internet) # 3Com Corporation 3c905C-TX/TX-M [Tornado]

[INTERNET]---[Motorola CableModem]----[eth1 LINUX-GW eth0]-----[LAN]---[desktop machines]
```

And now it works perfectly! How can this be?

Notice that it's not simply that the "Sundance" NIC has some problem, as in the current configuration, when I do the tests,  from a LAN machine, I'm still going through the two cards as before (only that in different order). Furthermore, when I transfer inside the LAN (desktop <-> GW) it works at a good Ethernet speed.

Has someone a plausible explanation, or experienced some similar bahaviour?

Comment: If possible, I would replace _both_ NICs. Those things are so ancient they belong in a museum!

Answer (score 1):

The only explanation I can think of is the cable connecting the gateway to the modem is going bad.

Perhaps the baseband chip (the one actually doing the line encoding/decoding) is going bad, or is not that good from the start, so that the increase in line noise (due to degraded cable) confuses it significantly.

Try checking the error rate using **ethtool**; compare the results to the other NIC's. It might help shed some light.

Answer (score 1):

One plausible explanation is a duplex negotiation failure between the sundance card and your DSL modem.

10/100Mbit ethernet was notorious for bad duplex negotiation.  Many people recommended hard-coding the  speed and duplex on both ends.  I wasn't a big fan of this, but it was not unreasonable.

It has become less of a problem over the years.  Gigabit ethernet auto-negotiation is reliable - in part, because there is no such thing as half-duplex gigabit.  I imagine that the 10/100 autonegotiation has gotten smarter too with newer chipsets.

Comment: Possibly more a case of getting more compatible, rather than smarter, but maybe that too.